# How to implement pagination in wordpress custom template page with author specific posts

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I want to list posts of current logged in author on a custom template page with pagination at the downside which has numbers with link of respective pages and at the upper side a drop down from which we will select how many posts will show on that page(this is working fine) but when i try to go to second page link at down side pagination it is going to page 2 but always shows same posts.
[Image view of template page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PffoH.png)

I have done some searching and implemented below code
form to show dropdown

```html
<form name="frm" class="db_posts_per_page_form" method="post" action="">
      <label for="db_posts_per_page">Posts per page</label>
      <select onchange="document.frm.submit()" name="db_posts_per_page" id="db_posts_per_page">
       <option value="2" <?php selected(2,$_REQUEST['db_posts_per_page']);?>>2</option>
       <option value="4" <?php selected(4,$_REQUEST['db_posts_per_page']);?>>4</option>
       <option value="6" <?php selected(6,$_REQUEST['db_posts_per_page']);?>>6</option>
       <option value="8" <?php selected(8,$_REQUEST['db_posts_per_page']);?>>8</option>
       <option value="10" <?php selected(10,$_REQUEST['db_posts_per_page']);?>>10</option>
      </select>
     </form>
```

and php for pagination

```
global $current_user;
                        if( isset($_POST['db_posts_per_page'] )):
                            $posts_per_page = $_POST['db_posts_per_page'];
                        else:
                            $posts_per_page = 2;
                        endif;
                        $author_query = array('posts_per_page' => $posts_per_page,'author' => $current_user->ID, 'post_status' => array('publish', 'pending', 'draft'));
                        $author_posts = new WP_Query($author_query);
                        while($author_posts->have_posts()) : $author_posts->the_post();
                            get_template_part( 'parts/post/content', 'blog-list' );
                        endwhile;
                        //global $author_posts;
                        $big = 999999999;
                        $paginate_links =  paginate_links ( array(
                        'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),
                        'format' => '?paged=%#%',
                        'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
                        'total' => $author_posts->max_num_pages,
                        'mid_size' => 5,
                        'prev_next' => true,
                        ) );
                         if (!empty($paginate_links)) : ?>
                            <div class="pagignation"><?php echo $paginate_links;?></div>
                        <?php endif;
```

Comment: And, have you verified whether your script receives that value? Why POST btw., for  pagination you should rather go with GET.

Comment: My script is receiving the value and i have tried with GET also but nothing more happens with that. And when i print_r($author_posts); it gives me the array in which data are present.

Comment: i have managed to do this with changing below

Comment: i have managed to do this with changing $autho_query to "$author_query = new WP_Query( array('posts_per_page'=>$posts_per_page,                'post_type'=>'post', 'author' => $current_user->ID, 'post_status' => array('publish', 'pending', 'draft'), 'paged' => get_query_var('paged') ? get_query_var('paged') : 1));" and by adding   wp_reset_postdata();  before echo the  $paginate_links

Answer (score 0):

I have changed  $author_query to  `$author_query = new WP_Query( array('posts_per_page'=>$posts_per_page,                'post_type'=>'post', 'author' => $current_user->ID, 'post_status' => array('publish', 'pending', 'draft'), 'paged' => get_query_var('paged') ? get_query_var('paged') : 1));`  and by adding   wp_reset_postdata();  before echo the  $paginate_links

So my whole code for that custom template page is now like below.

```
<div id="primary" class="content-area">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12">
                <h1 class="page-title"><?php the_title();?></h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row add-new">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
                <form name="frm" class="db_posts_per_page_form" method="get" action="">
                    <label for="db_posts_per_page">Posts per page</label>
                    <select onchange="document.frm.submit()" name="db_posts_per_page" id="db_posts_per_page">
                        <option value="2" <?php selected(2,$_REQUEST['db_posts_per_page']);?>>2</option>
                        <option value="4" <?php selected(4,$_REQUEST['db_posts_per_page']);?>>4</option>
                        <option value="6" <?php selected(6,$_REQUEST['db_posts_per_page']);?>>6</option>
                        <option value="8" <?php selected(8,$_REQUEST['db_posts_per_page']);?>>8</option>
                        <option value="10" <?php selected(10,$_REQUEST['db_posts_per_page']);?>>10</option>
                    </select>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
                <div class="pull-right col-xs-12 col-md-3"><a class="btn btn-primary" href="<?php echo esc_url( get_permalink(80) ); ?>">Add New Posts</a></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4">
                <h5><u>Title</u></h5>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-2">
                <h5><u>Author</u></h5>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-2">
                <h5><u>Status</u></h5>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-2">
                <h5><u>Posted On</u></h5>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-2">
                <h5><u>Actions</u></h5>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12">
                <?php if ( is_user_logged_in() ):
                        global $current_user;
                        if( isset($_GET['db_posts_per_page'] )):
                            $posts_per_page = $_GET['db_posts_per_page'];
                        else:
                            $posts_per_page = 2;
                        endif;
                        //echo $posts_per_page;

                        $author_query = new WP_Query( array('posts_per_page'=>$posts_per_page,
                             'post_type'=>'post',
                             'author' => $current_user->ID,
                             'post_status' => array('publish', 'pending', 'draft'),
                             'paged' => get_query_var('paged') ? get_query_var('paged') : 1) 
                        ); 

                        //print_r($author_query);
                        while($author_query->have_posts()) : $author_query->the_post();
                            get_template_part( 'parts/post/content', 'blog-list' );
                        endwhile;

                        $big = 999999999;
                        $paginate_links =  paginate_links ( array(
                        'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),
                        'format' => '?paged=%#%',
                        'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
                        'total' => $author_query->max_num_pages,
                        'mid_size' => 5,
                        'prev_next' => true,
                        ) );
                        wp_reset_postdata();
                         if (!empty($paginate_links)) : ?>
                            <div class="pagignation"><?php echo $paginate_links;?></div>
                        <?php endif; 
                      else:
                        echo 'You need to be logged in to see your posts.';
                endif;?>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```